# Angular 2 form field generated Id

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am looking for a way to dynamically generate an id for my dynamic form field.

For use on the id etc. I am after something similar to the id's in augury

[image]

Comment: One option i am exploring is to create a service to generate an id randomly, but if there is something baked into angular2 that would be better.

Comment: Angular2 doesn't provide anything for generating IDs. I remember seeing a feature request but it was declined bacause it's too simple to do your own.

Comment: I thought as much, was just double checking i wasn't missing something, reinventing the wheel and all that.